# How can i request to access my json.json data from my homepage?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, cross-domain

Please help me i cant get data from my homepage 
My AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
                url:"http://example.com/json.json?jsoncallback=?",
                type:"GET",
                dataType:"jsonp",
                beforeSend:function(){
                    console.log("before send");
                },
                success:function(data,status){
                 console.log("success");
                }  
            });
```

And json.json file in my homepage

```
> {   "firstName": "John",   "lastName": "Smith",   "isAlive": true,  
> "age": 25,   "address": {
>     "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
>     "city": "New York",
>     "state": "NY",
>     "postalCode": "10021-3100"   },   "phoneNumbers": [
>     {
>       "type": "home",
>       "number": "212 555-1234"
>     },
>     {
>       "type": "office",
>       "number": "646 555-4567"
>     },
>     {
>       "type": "mobile",
>       "number": "123 456-7890"
>     }   ],   "children": [],   "spouse": null }
```

Please suggest i tried a lot by searching on google and here but can't understand

Answer (score 0):

The error I observed is use of datatype jsonp where as the original data is in json format.
Hence, below block of code should work well if it is not a cross-domain request.

```
 $.ajax({
      url : "http://example.com/json.json",
      type : "GET",
      success:function(data,status){
        console.log(data); //json data from the requested url
      },
      failure:(xhr,responseText,status){
        //failure block
      }
    });
```

But in your case if it is a cross domain request and you don't have your json data surrounded by a callback function, below block of code will work well, but you'll have to import yql library on your page https://github.com/hail2u/jquery.query-yql :

```
function getCrossDomainData(){
    try{
        var site = "http://example.com/json.json";
        var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from json where url="' + site + '"') + '&format=json&callback=cbFunc';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
        });
        function cbFunc(data) {
            // get the data in this block
        }
    }catch(err){
        console.log("Err in getCrossDomainData : "+err);
    }
}
```